# AWS S3 CLI multipart upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multipart, aws-cli

When trying to upload a file to an AWS S3 bucket using the aws-cli, does it automatically use multipart upload on bigger files? Because all it outputs is

`Completed 3.0 GiB/9.4 GiB (18.4 MiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining`

which does not make me any wiser.

I checked several other information sources and this [this page](https://www.systutorials.com/239665/uploading-large-files-amazon-s3-aws-cli/) tells me it goes automatically, while the Amazon help tells me otherwise.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They do mention in AWS docs that the CLI commands automatically perform a multipart upload for large objects.

Excerpt [from documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/using-s3-commands.html):

> All high-level commands that involve uploading objects into an Amazon
>   S3 bucket (`aws s3 cp`, `aws s3 mv`, and `aws s3 sync`) automatically
>   perform a multipart upload when the object is large.
>
> Failed uploads cannot be resumed when using these commands. If the
>   multipart upload fails due to a timeout or is manually cancelled by
>   pressing <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd>, the AWS CLI cleans up any files created
>   and aborts the upload. This process can take several minutes.
>
> If the process is interrupted by a kill command or system failure, the
>   in-progress multipart upload remains in Amazon S3 and must be cleaned
>   up manually in the AWS Management Console or with the
>   [`s3api abort-multipart-upload`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/abort-multipart-upload.html) command.